# tensorflow conv1d, in this code why I can not use a kernel_size of 2 or 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have this code

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['tfidf'] = [[[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)],[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)]],
              [[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)],[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)]],
              [[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)],[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)]],
              [[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)],[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)]]]

df['is_similar'] = np.random.randint(0,2, 4)

def getmodel():
    x_input = keras.Input(shape=(2, 30), name="article1")  # Variable-length sequence of ints
    conv1d_1 = layers.Conv1D(64, 1, activation='relu')(x_input)
    flat = layers.Flatten()(conv1d_1)
    dense1 = layers.Dense(1024, name="dense1", activation="relu")(flat)
    encoder_conv_dense2 = layers.Dense(256, name="40_dense", activation="relu")(dense1)
    encoder_conv_dense3 = layers.Dense(1, name="similar_result", activation="sigmoid")(encoder_conv_dense2)

    model = keras.Model(
        inputs=x_input,
        outputs=encoder_conv_dense3,
    )

    return model


model = getmodel()
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy')
history = model.fit(
    {"article1": np.stack(df['tfidf'], 0)},
    {"similar_result": df['is_similar']},
    epochs=3,
)
```

since I have for every input a matrix of 2 rows and 30 columns, I suppose the kernel_size can be 2,3,5,9 ... < 30, but in this particular model the only option that allows me is kernel_size=1, other different values generate the following error:

example using

> conv1d_1 = layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu')(x_input)

```
raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for '{{node conv1d/conv1d}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](conv1d/conv1d/ExpandDims, conv1d/conv1d/ExpandDims_1)' with input shapes: [?,1,2,30], [1,3,30,64].
```

Could someone please help me with this misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand entirely how your model should process the data, but you need extra feature channel in addition to the dimension which has 30 elements on which you perform convolution. You perhaps want to treat rows as sort of sub-batch of sequences, for this keras has TimeDistributed. Here's warning: you have 1 as the dimension before the last in your data, but you set 2 for input.

If I misunderstood your idea, you can start modifying from here.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['tfidf'] = [[[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)],[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)]],
              [[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)],[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)]],
              [[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)],[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)]],
              [[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)],[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)]]]

df['is_similar'] = np.random.randint(0,2, 4)


def getmodel():
    x_input = keras.Input(shape=(2, 30), name="article1")  # Variable-length sequence of ints
    # add one feature channel
    x_input1 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x,-1))(x_input)
    # timedistributed makes second dimension after batch dim sort of second batch dimension
    conv1d_1 = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))(x_input1)
    # will have 64 feature channels
    #print(conv1d_1)
    #Tensor("time_distributed/Reshape_1:0", shape=(?, 2, 30, 64), dtype=float32)
    flat = layers.Flatten()(conv1d_1)
    dense1 = layers.Dense(1024, name="dense1", activation="relu")(flat)
    encoder_conv_dense2 = layers.Dense(256, name="40_dense", activation="relu")(dense1)
    encoder_conv_dense3 = layers.Dense(1, name="similar_result", activation="sigmoid")(encoder_conv_dense2)

    model = keras.Model(
        inputs=x_input,
        outputs=encoder_conv_dense3,
    )

    return model


model = getmodel()
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy')
# removed 1 dimension from array shape # (4, 2, 1, 30)
history = model.fit(
    {"article1": np.stack(df['tfidf'], 0).squeeze()},
    {"similar_result": df['is_similar']},
    epochs=3,
)
```

Comment: I do not understand why I need to add channels. let me try to explain, in every input, I have a matrix of 2 rows and 30 columns, every row is a different metric that I want to compare with conv1d. I mean I have a matrix where every row has the form of [ [metric1(length 30), metric2(length 30)],  per input, that is why I write an "Input(shape=(2, 30)".  The solution of adding a channel works well, just, could you help me to understand what I did wrong and why I need to add "x_input1 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x,-1))(x_input)". thanks in advance

Comment: @FerminPitol Sorry, I don't get how do you want to compare two series with convolution and what should be the output of it. Technically, 1d convolution needs input to have at least two dimensions: `(..., datapoints, input_feature_channels)`. Thus convolution algoritm is applied for the sliding window moving across all the datapoints, each of the form `(1, input_feature_channels)`. The number of outputs will be the number of output channels (number of different filters for the convolution), in your case 64: `x64 of (1, input_feature_channels)*conv -> (1, 64)`.

Comment: @FerminPitol You wanted to apply convolution with filter size 2, 3 (2,3,5,9 ... < 30) which is impossible for 2 data points with 30 features each, so I decided that 2 is a number of sequences in batch, 30 is actual data points. Therefore you need to create at least one input feature channel.